# ¿A qué se debe éste error en asp.net No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List<bool>' en 'bool'?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Este es parte de mi código y también donde se muestra el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error te dice que existe una lista `List<bool>` que NO entra en un tipo `bool`. Dicho en otro modo: ese `tiene_permiso` debería ser una lista y en lugar de preguntar `if(!tiene_permiso)` debería ser `if(!tiene_permiso.Any())`

Comment: Gracias! Amigo  se eliminaron las lineas de error.

Comment: Si esto solucionó tu problema, al costado hay un check para dar click y marcar como aceptada la respuesta, esto ayuda a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.